# Append to current copy buffer

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I am copying multiple lines from different parts.

I can for example do
`3yy`
to copy the 3 next lines.

Then I would like to scroll a bit and add 5 more lines:
`5yy`

and so on.
At the end, I want to paste all lines (in this case 8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append to the *named* registers `"a` through `"z`, in which case you use the lowercase versions of the registers to overwrite/replace their contents and the uppercase version to append to their contents.

So you can use `"a3yy` (or `3"ayy`) for the initial yank of 3 lines, then `"A5yy` (or `5"Ayy`) to append the 5 next lines to that same register, which you can then put using `"ap` (or `"Ap` also works.)

See [`:help "a`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quotea) for details.

A neat trick to use when appending to named registers is that you can use the `q` command (which records macros) to empty the registers. For example, `qaq` will clear register `"a`. (It starts recording a macro into register `"a`, and then the second `q` ends the recording right away.) By clearing the register first, you can then use the uppercase register for appending on the first yank, which can be useful if you're using a repeated command such as a macro or a `:g` command to yank multiple lines.